# Ember Simple Auth: 'authorize' is deprecated

Tags: ember.js, deprecation-warning

Here is my code:

```
"ember-simple-auth": "^1.6.0"

"ember-cli": "^3.1.4"


export default ActiveModelAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin, {
  host: ENV.APP.API_HOST,  
  authorizer: 'authorizer:devise',
...
```

How can I fix deprecation warning ?

Comment: The deprecation comes with a [link to the documentation](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#deprecation-of-authorizers) explaining how to fix it, give it a look.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the solution is provided by the addon authors within the deprecation message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed this issue. See the [examples in the documentation](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#authorizers).

```
authorize(xhr) {
    let { email, token } = this.get('session.data.authenticated');
    let authData = `Token token="${token}", email="${email}"`;
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authData);
}
```

Use above code instead of `authorizer: 'authorizer:devise'`.